# Specify time when IIS 7 logs roll over daily

Tags: iis, iis-7

I have an IIS 7.0 server configured to rollover logs daily. However it appears that the logs rollover at 10am each day. How/where do I configure this so that they roll over at 1am?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logs use UTC and roll-over UTC day bounaries, this is by-design.

You can switch to Local Time by checking the "[ ] Use local time for file naming and rollover" box on the Logging screen in IIS Manager.

Besides local vs UTC, you cannot specify a custom timezone or arbitrary point in time for the rollover.

Comment: That explains it. We are UTC+10. So changed to local time and all should be good now. Thanks.